# How to Assign a Dynamic Value to a Toast Notification

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, toast

I am creating a toast notification for a UWP app, and I have run into a snag. I desire to send the user a message with a quote from an author;

[image: Notification]

I have a [list of 137 quotes](https://github.com/CyanCoding/Motivational-Text-Selector) that I am reading from, so the toast notification cannot have a static quote or author value. Here's the notification structure:

```
// Global quote variables
static string quote;
static string author;

// Toast struct
ToastContent toastContent = new ToastContent() {
    Visual = new ToastVisual() {
        BindingGeneric = new ToastBindingGeneric() {
            Children = {
                // Bold title text
                new AdaptiveText() {
                    Text = "Motivational Reminder"
                },
                // Body text
                new AdaptiveText() {
                    Text = quote
                }
            },
            // Small attribution text
            Attribution = new ToastGenericAttributionText() {
                Text = author
            }
        }
    },
    // Notification on-click
    Launch = new QueryString() {
        {"action", "nothing" }
    }.ToString()
};
```

**I init the quote and author variables from another function before creating the toast, of course.** I've debugged the program, and I can see that the variables get initialized before I try and make the toast, but they always come out as null:

[image: Null notification text]

The `RawValue` value should resemble the quote in the above picture. How can I otherwise assign a dynamic value to my notification?

I have looked through the Microsoft notification docs, but they always have text present in the example, rather than sourcing it from an outside variable. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts#text-elements).

Comment: I used your code to test but the result is correct. What I did is to create a blank app, put a button on the XAML page, and add your code to the button click event. I gave values to these static properties when I initialized the page. When I click the button to show the notification, the values are shown correctly. Have you double-checked if these properties are not null before you create the notification?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Yes, I debugged and saw that the values had been set before the notification was initialized.

Comment: Could you please try to create a blank app like what I did to test? Does it happen in the new blank app as well?